# On change not working when check operation performed by button

Tags: jquery, checkbox, onchange

I have these checkboxes that has change event. When i check these checkboxes via button.Change event doesn't fire. Whats wrong with it?

**Html**

```
  <button>aaa</button>  
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox"> 
  <input type="checkbox"> 
  <input type="checkbox">
```

**Jquery**

```
$(':checkbox').on('change',function(){
 alert("checked"); 
});

$('button').on('click',function(){
  $(':checkbox').prop('checked',true);
});
```

Demo http://jsbin.com/idiweJo/1/

Comment: What do you mean with _via external button_? You mean the button you have next to the checkboxes?

Comment: @putvande my bad. edited it to button :). yup nxt to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply call the change function again after checking it in button click

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
  $(':checkbox').prop('checked',true).change();
});
```

**note: since you are checking all the checkboxes , the change event is fired for each checkbox..**

Comment: Can u pls explain. Why do i have to trigger change? tnx

Comment: because you are progammatically changing the checkbox value property.. the browser will not be able to track the changed event of that element... so you have to trigger it manually trigger it

Comment: How can i run alert only once?

Comment: well that depends on what you want to do in change event... do you have to check all the checkboxes when that button is clicked ??

Answer (score 1):

you have to use trigger function for this..

check this jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/gkCfZ/

```
$(':checkbox').on('change',function(){
 alert("checked"); 
});

$('button').on('click',function(){
  $(':checkbox').prop('checked',true);
    $(':checkbox').trigger("change");
});
```